# Is there an ant library to execute remote commands in an ant like fashion?

Tags: ant, ssh

I am not talking about sshexec task, i want a lib that will allow me to use all the power of ant but instead of doing stuff locally it will do it on a remote host.

For example using copy, move rename and more but in a remote host and not locally.

I know sshexec can acheive similar things, but once i log in to the machine i have to use shell, instead i want to be able to use normal ant tasks.

EDIT:

I have just found out about `sshsession` task that lets you encapsulate ant tasks to run remotely, or at least thats what the manual says: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshsession.html

I have tested it with this simple build.xml:

```
<project name="project" default="default">

    <!-- ================================= 
          target: default              
         ================================= -->
    <target name="default" description="description">
        <sshsession host="${host}" username="${username}" password="${password}" trust="yes">
            <sequential>
                <mkdir dir="/tmp/sshtest"/>             
            </sequential>
        </sshsession>

    </target>


</project>
```

I get the following result when running it:

```
 default:

    [sshsession] Connecting to my.server
        [mkdir] Created dir: C:\tmp\sshtest
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Instead of creating the dir on the remote server it creates it locally on my PC. Any idea  ?

Comment: I guess `sshsession` does not perform what I thought it does. so my question remains open.

Comment: What your looking for is difficult without assuming software is first installed on the remote node. To obtain "the power of ant" you'd have to first upload the ANT jars.

Comment: sshsession is meant to open a tunnel between local computer and remote computer, with which some applications could have access to some services (network ports) as if they are in the same machine. If you really want to run something on the remote machine, you have to deploy something first -- no matter what it may be.

Comment: did you meet following prerequisite of the `sshsession` task? *This task depends on external libraries not included in the Ant distribution. See Library Dependencies for more information. This task has been tested with jsch-0.1.33 and above and won't work with versions of jsch earlier than 0.1.28*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's quite what you are after by you could try [AntServer / RemoteAnt](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html) from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out for me, as you said not exactly what i need but its the closest there is i guess.